# Report Server - Can't declare parameters

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

My problem is that I was not able to declare parameters through Report Builder.

I was receiving the following error:

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must
>   declare the scalar variable "@param".

So I googled it and found that it can be solved easily by putting symbol "?" instead of "@parameter" and it did solved my problem for a while.

But now I have another problem. I have a `select` like:

```
select * from table t where t.date = ? or t.date2 = ? or t.date3 = ?
```

Where all three "?" are '2013-aug-01', but each "?" creates a new parameter in the parameters section of Report Builder.

How can I use one parameter for all three cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from table t where ? IN (t.date, t.date2, t.date3)
```

Another way of solving is just delete the two variables created by SSRS and update your query to

```
select * from table t where t.date = @param1 or t.date2 = @param1 or t.date3 = @param1
```

Another method write your query

```
select * from table t where t.date = ? or t.date2 = ? or t.date3 = ?
```

Let it create the 3 variables. Then go to Dataset, under dataset properties goto parameters section. There update the parameter value of 2 & 3 to Parameter1. Next go in the parameters section and delete the automatically generated Parameter2 & Parameter3.

Comment: thanks for the reply,

I can't use first example because the fields that I'm trying to check are not under the same "where" (sub select, union and etc.)
and as for the second suggestion, I can't use "@" symbol. for some unknown reasons it does not recognizes it as report builder's parameter identifier but as query's variable and because of this I receive an error saying that first I have to declare variable before using it.

Comment: I added the 3rd method. Check it out.